# Flask - storing dropdown value from template

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a Flask / Postgres app and running into an issue with a dropdown I've built - I can't figure out how to store a selected value from the dropdown in my database. Please let me know what I'm missing. I have googled around but most of the relevant answers pertain to PHP not Flask.

Here's my flask view:

```
@app.route('/logworkout', methods=['POST'])
def post_log_workout(): 
try:   
    studio = (request.form.get['studio'])
    instructor = (request.form.get['instructor'])        
    workout = Workout(studio=studio, instructor=instructor)
    db.session.add(workout)
    db.session.commit()        
except:
    return render_template("submit_workout.html", studio="", instructor="",
    error="Error, your log is incomplete! Please check and submit it again!")
return render_template("submit_workout.html", studio=studio, instructor=instructor, error="")
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<form action="" method='post'>    
  <h3>2. Which Studio?</h3>
  <select name='studio'>
      <option value='Name1'>LongerName1</option>
      <option value='Name2'>LongerName2</option>
      <option value='Name3'>LongerName3</option>          
  </select>

      <h3>2. Which Instructor?</h3>
  <select name='instructor'>
      <option value='Name1'>LongerName1</option>
      <option value='Name2'>LongerName2</option>
      <option value='Name3'>LongerName3</option>          
  </select>

<input type='submit' value='submit'>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a few things to correct.

First, a Flask view should have both GET and POST and I would re-arrange your view code as:

```
@app.route('/logworkout', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post_log_workout(): 
    error=""
    if request.method == 'POST':   
        studio = (request.form.get['studio'])
        instructor = (request.form.get['instructor'])
        if studio is not None and instructor is not None:       
            workout = Workout(studio=studio, instructor=instructor)
            db.session.add(workout)
            db.session.commit() 
            # you can redirect to home page on successful commit. or anywhere else
            return redirect(url_for('index'))       
        else:
            error="Error, your log is incomplete! Please check and submit it again!")

    return render_template("submit_workout.html", error=error)
```

You only need to have the render_template once in your code. The way it will work is when a GET request is fired i.e. you visit the url /logworkout first time, the form will be displayed which once entered and posted, will then  redirect to home page or wherever.

In your form code, your form action should not be blank. You need to call the view by using url_for() method

Change this

```
# Incorrect
<form action="" method='post'>
```

to

```
# Correct
<form action="{{ url_for('post_log_workout') }}" method='post'>
```

Comment: Why should the view support GET too, exactly? That's not required here.

Comment: Wouldn't you initially render the submit_workout.html template through GET ?

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't appear to be the issue here; I think we can assume there is a separate route that handles the initial form rendering.

Comment: yes if there is a separate route, then correct. I was just assuming based on the code that this route handles both the rendering and submission. And you are right that this is not the main issue but I thought to let the OP know to use one view and not have the return statement multiple times.

Comment: Yes there is a separate route supporting GET which handles the form rendering (I didn't post it here as I didn't think necessary). Thank you for cleaning up my code! After debugging for sometime, I learned that it wasn't my dropdown code which was the issue - the models.py import was not working and hence the value from the dropdown was not being stored!